# Neither A nor B equals C - A and B always separate entities?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I found an example of "neither/nor" on a site about logic puzzles:

> **Neither the pink tattoo nor the Pisces was Sheila's.**

It states:

- Sheila didn't get the pink tattoo, and Sheila didn't get the Pisces tattoo.
- The pink tattoo wasn't the Pisces.

About the second statement it says:

> The "neither/nor" construct tells you that the two items being discussed in relation to Sheila (i.e. the pink tattoo and the Pisces tattoo) are two separate entities.

Is that correct? The Pisces tattoo cannot be pink?

Here's another example:

> Neither squares nor sculptures are blue.

So, squares cannot be sculptures?

Comment: Logic puzzles don't necessarily use words (especially logical operators) in the usual way. In particular, in ordinary language "A or B" does not necessarily exclude the possibility of both, but in a logic problem it may do so.

Comment: But "either A or B" would exclude the possibility of both, right?

Comment: Sometimes, but not always. Language is language, not logic.

Answer (score 2):

> The "neither/nor" construct tells you that the two items being discussed in relation to Sheila (i.e. the pink tattoo and the Pisces tattoo) are two separate entities.

This is false. Normally, you wouldn't use "neither A nor B" if you *knew* that A and B were identical; if the pink tattoo were the Pisces one, you would say "the pink Pisces tattoo wasn't Sheila's."

But saying "neither A nor B" doesn't *entail* that A and B are distinct. This is particularly obvious in the plural case, as your "neither squares nor sculptures" example indicates.